# Can a redblack tree cope with this comparison function?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was thinking to use a RedBlack tree that does not support multiple insertion of the same key using a comparison function similar to this one:

```
int compare(MyObject A, MyObject B)
{
   if (A.error > B.error) return 1;
   if (A.error < B.error) return -1;
   if (A.name == B.name) return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

this trick would be useful to have multiple items with the same error, but different "name". If two items with the same error are found, but the value does not coincide, the comparing item is just treated as "bigger".

I am pretty sure that this trick would work with a normal BST...but I am having troubles with a redblack tree. I do not know the redblack tree algorithm, I am using an implementation, so I wonder if there is any reason why this should not work.

P.S.: name does not have a comparison relationship...so the only thing I can do is to check if they are the same.

P.P.S.: assuming that this does not work and knowing that I cannot have a order relation between the "name" values, what other possibilities do I have? I could use a data structure that allow to insert multiple values with the same key, but that won't work for me, because when I delete a value, I must be sure that I am deleting the value I am actually passing (basically for me the key and the value hare the same thing, I need a sort of ordered multiset data structure!)

Comment: As long as you define an order relation it will be ok. You should work with a kind of lexicographic order on your objects. The priority should be given to the error and the value should be examined if two objects are having the same error.

Comment: yes this is what I wrote correct? But with all the implementations I tried so far (3!!)it resulted in to errors....at a given point the search function could not find an item that actually was in the collection.

Comment: Your relation is not transitive

Comment: could you please give me more details? If you mean that the value must comparable...well it is not, I actually compare references.

Comment: A relation `<` is said to be transitive if, given that `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c`. Since you always return 1 if the value fields of your objects are not equal, you cannot enforce this behavior

Comment: Is `name` field a string ?

Comment: well in my real case it is an object reference...I did not want to write the real code that actually looks like this, but it is harder to explain: 
public int CompareTo(DualCubeEdge other)
{
      if (error < other.error) return -1;
      else 
    if (error > other.error) return 1;
      else 
  if ((other.A == A && other.B == B) || (other.A == B && other.B == A)) 
  return 0;
   else 
   return 1;
    }

Comment: I guess you are using `Java` or `C++` then. Can you define an order relation between your objects ?

Comment: @sebas: If all you can do with `name` is test for equality then you can't use it as part of your key (you must be able to order the keys). One workaround to consider is only using errors as keys and have your nodes contain a `names` set instead of a single `name` object.

Comment: it's c#, I cannot, the problem is that for me the fact that the error is the same it is not enough to decide that the object is actually the same. Multiple objects with different A and B can have the same error.

Comment: @missingno: so forcing the key to be seen as "greater" if the name are different is not correct, is it? Is still a relation. I am quite sure that it worked for me in the past with a normal BST

Comment: @sebas: Its a relation, but its not an ordering relation. For example, we should expect that `compare(A,B) == 1` should imply `compare(B,A) == -1` and the binary tree is going to rely on that assumption but your current function breaks this promise if you have A and B with the same error but different values. As an aside, this reminds me of the [IE browser-choice bug](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html), where using an invalid comparison function would lead to a biased shuffle.

Comment: @sebas: The broken compare function should work only as long as you don't do any balancing in the tree or remove any of the nodes. For example, lets pretend that the comparison function always returns 1. You will always go to the right when searching or inserting an element but its going to work because all the elements are going to be inserted in that rightmost branch anyway. However, if you rebalance the tree then some elements are not going to be on the rightmost branch anymore and your search wont find them even though they are there.

Comment: yeah that is what I thought! that it does not work because of the rebalancing...but I am not sure why the remove on a normal BST should not work. Btw, thank you very much for your time

Comment: @sebas: The problem is doing insertions after the remove operation changes the tree structure: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLhuE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary search trees expect your comparison function to obey the usual rules for a [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) over the elements you are going to insert into the tree. Your current comparison function doesn't obey this because if you have objects A and B with the same `error` key but different `value`  keys then according to `compare` you both `A < B` and `B < A` are valid.

I think it should all work correctly if you change your comparison function to

```
int compare(MyObject A, MyObject B)
{
   if (A.error > B.error) return 1;
   if (A.error < B.error) return -1;
   if (A.value > B.value) return 1;
   if (A.value < B.value) return -1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: true, but the problem is that I cannot compare A and B if not just for equality.

Comment: I accept your answer because you made me realize I have to review some of the algorithm theories :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not define an order relation.

In your case, your objects are two-dimensional. I understand from your question that the priority in ordering should be given to the `error` field. Thus, an order relation (using lexicographic order) should be :

```
struct my_object {
    int error;
    int value;
};

int compare(struct my_object *a, struct my_object *b)
{
    int ret;
    if (!a) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (!b) {
        return -1;
    }
    ret = a->error - b->error;
    if (!ret) {
        ret = a->value - b->value;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: ok, my fault, value is not comparable...I actually need to compare two references of instances of object...

Comment: Can you please tell me more about the fields type ?

Comment: they are actually objects :/